# USB/SATA cable simply does not work on Ubuntu

Tags: usb, mount, sata

I couldn't find an answer to my problem because all other similar questions have Ubuntu properly recognize the external HDD as a storage medium and assign it to /dev/sdb. If only it were this easy. It doesn't matter what HDD I plug into the cable, Ubuntu just does not recognize it. A /dev/sd[x] link is never assigned to it. lsusb lists the drive as `ID 1234:5678 Brain Actuated Technologies VLI Product String` (which gives zero hits on Google). I've hit a brick wall and don't know what else to do to access the files on the external hard drives.

This is the dmesg output:

```
[  812.784132] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  813.672420] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  813.700812] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1234, idProduct=5678, bcdDevice= 3.00
[  813.700820] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  813.700824] usb 2-3: Product: VLI Product String
[  813.700828] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: VLI manufacture String
[  813.700831] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 000000001F4E
[  813.703047] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  813.703540] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-3:1.0
```

I don't know if this is relevant, but my cable has a separate USB dongle for power intake. The HDD is powered on and spins.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work with a different OS?

Comment: I don’t have any devices with other OSs I could test it on.